# Docker-compose + Kubernetes: backports.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a complete docker stack ([source](https://github.com/carlosas/docker-for-symfony-3)) which uses docker-compose.

It works fine by its own, but now I'm trying to deploy it in Kubernetes' Minikube and when after `eval $(minikube docker-env)` I try to run `docker-compose up`, it throws the following error:

> backports.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError: hostname '192.168.99.100' doesn't match 'localhost'

What am I missing?

---

This is the complete trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.8.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 61, in main
>       command()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 113, in perform_command
>       handler(command, command_options)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 835, in up
>       remove_orphans=remove_orphans)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 372, in up
>       warn_for_swarm_mode(self.client)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 539, in warn_for_swarm_mode
>       info = client.info()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 33, in info
>       return self._result(self._get(self._url("/info")), True)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
>       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 140, in _get
>       return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
>       return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
>       timeout=timeout
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 560, in urlopen
>       body=body, headers=headers)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
>       self._validate_conn(conn)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in _validate_conn
>       conn.connect()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 277, in connect
>       match_hostname(cert, asserted_hostname)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/ssl_match_hostname/**init**.py", line 99, in match_hostname
>       % (hostname, dnsnames[0]))
>
> backports.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError: hostname '192.168.99.100' doesn't match 'localhost'

Comment: Posibly related: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/225

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have missed DNS. First, don't reference the device by IP, instead use a FQDN. If you need, you can set an entry for 192.168.99.100 in /etc/hosts for now. Secondly, type "hostname" on the node and verify it does not return "localhost" (it likely will). Then type "hostnamectl set-hostname newhostname.fullyqualified.com" and then [regenerate and re-sign the certificate.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proper solution to fix the certs, but a work-around is to make docker-compose not care about the mismatch as follows:

`CURL_CA_BUNDLE= docker-compose up`